# Parse findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock return nil

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

This is my code in swift

```
class UserViewController: UITableViewController {

var userArray: NSMutableArray = []

@IBOutlet weak var friendListTableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       retrieveMessages()

   }
func retrieveMessages() {
    var query = PFUser.query()
    if let username = PFUser.currentUser().username {
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in

        for object in objects! {
            let usernames:String? = (object as PFObject)["Friends"] as? String
            println(usernames)
            if usernames != nil {
                self.userArray.addObject(usernames!)
            }
        }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.friendListTableView.reloadData()
                }

    }

}
}
            override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return userArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Update - replace as with as!

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = userArray[indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell
}
```

the problem is the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method return nil so my table won't update,the object contains array of friends that current user had. So how do I fix this? thanks in advance and let me know if you need more information!

Update: I've change my code to (I'm using Xcode 6.2)

```
class UserTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var userArray: [String] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    retrieveMessages()
}

func retrieveMessages() {
    var query = PFUser.query()!
    if let username = PFUser.currentUser()!.username {
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { [weak self]
            (objects, error) -> Void in
            println(objects)
            for object in objects! {
                let username:String? = (object as PFUser).username
                if username != nil {
                    self!.userArray.append(username!)
                }
            }
            self!.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return userArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = userArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

and my app crash, this is the error log

2015-06-08 01:41:32.944 ParseStarterProject[635:14183] Unknown class _TtC19ParseStarterProject18UserViewController in Interface Builder file.
2015-06-08 01:41:32.966 ParseStarterProject[635:14183] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key friendListTableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d35fa75 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010efeabb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d35f6b9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010d803d43 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d2a95e0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010dfec4ed -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010de4aa88 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010de4b078 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010e008bd8 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 76
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010de4b2e9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010de4b77e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010e3eef4e -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 65
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010de26d69 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 105
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010de57531 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 1746
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010de59871 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 132
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010de59795 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229
    16  ParseStarterProject                 0x000000010c81c1c0 _TFC19ParseStarterProject14ViewController13viewDidAppearfS0_FSbT_ + 1488
    17  ParseStarterProject                 0x000000010c81c231 _TToFC19ParseStarterProject14ViewController13viewDidAppearfS0_FSbT_ + 49
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010de4f361 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 567
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010de4feab -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 52
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010dd48adb _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010dd48974 _afterCACommitHandler + 547
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d294507 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d294460 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d28a293 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d289bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110a99a58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010dd25580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    28  ParseStarterProject                 0x000000010c8203ae top_level_code + 78
    29  ParseStarterProject                 0x000000010c82048a main + 42
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f802145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Update: fix the error and these are screenshots of my parse
my parse's class "User"
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xp48v3yn0l2hje/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-03%20at%202.10.13%20PM.png?dl=0
This is my current user's friend list inside "Friends" column
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd8mt8sf35u1m0v/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-03%20at%202.10.55%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: What investigation have you done? What were the results? What does `println(usernames)` print? Did you inspect the `error` object? What does that say? How do you know the result *shouldn't* be `nil`? Does this user have any friends?

Comment: Does the code crash? Because if the result is nil, objects! should throw an error

Comment: @sin90 give some info about whether you are getting any error or app crashes or not...

Comment: the println(usernames) returns nil and I know it shouldn't be nil because I've saved user's friend list in parse and when I check it at the parse web site, it exists inside Friends column of parse's class name "User" and no, my app did not crash, but the method itself didn't get any object so my tableview's empty

Comment: I want to retrieve my friends column in User's class, I've update my code and my app crash, error log's in the question. any help is appreciated  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PFUser.query only queries the User table. It looks like what you really want to query is "Friends" table or a "Messages" table. Different queries have different types of objects to cast to, e.g. PFObject, PFUser... If you do want to query User table, you can find the working code below:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class UserTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var userArray = ["Jane","Ann"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         retrieveMessages()
    }

    func retrieveMessages() {
        var query = PFUser.query()!
        if let username = PFUser.currentUser()!.username {
            query.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { [weak self]
                (objects, error) -> Void in
                println(objects)
                for object in objects! {
                    let username:String? = (object as! PFUser).username
                    if username != nil {
                        self!.userArray.append(username!)
                    }
                }
                self!.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return userArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = userArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

If you want to query other table, you have to change PFUser.query to PFQuery. I recently went through the same problem. You can find the sample code I wrote [here](https://github.com/vidaaudrey/028-Hello-Friend-Parse-Chat-App/blob/master/HelloFriend/MyApp/FriendsViewController.swift)

Comment: I want to retrieve my friends column in User's class and I've tried your code and it crash, I've update the log in the question,Thank you!

Comment: It's the problem of the interface builder and controller hookup. You created an outlet "@IBOutlet weak var friendListTableView: UITableView!" from the interface builder, but it can't find the code in your controller.  Note: default UITableViewController already has a tableView property, that's why I used self!tableView.reloadData() without creating any other tableView outlet.  You can either delete the outlet reference from IB, or add the "@IBOutlet weak var friendListTableView: UITableView!" in the code, also update  "self!tableView.reloadData()" to "self!friendListTableView.reloadData()

Comment: Yeah! problem solved but my tableView's still empty, I want to get my current user's friend list so I must query "Friends" and not "User" right? If I want to do that what should be changed in my code?. Thanks!

Comment: It depends how you structure you data in Parse. If you stored a friends list (typically an array of friends' names) in User table, then you must query User table. If you have a separate table "Friends" storing the relationship, you must query "Friends" using PFQuery. Since this is a one-to-many relationship, I'd suggest using the second approach.

Comment: what code do I have to right to query this? Thanks!

Comment: Say you have a table at Parse named "Friends" and it has "from" and "to " fields.         func retrieveFriends() { var query = PFQuery(className: "Friends")  if let username = PFUser.currentUser()!.username { query.whereKey("from", equalTo: username) query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ [weak self] (objects, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil && objects?.count > 0 { if let friend = objects![0] as? PFObject { let to:String = friend["to"]! as! String
                            self!.userArray.append(to)
                }
                    }
                })
        }

Comment: i fix it as you say well, the table's still empty and the println print "Optional([])" . Why does it keep empty?

Comment: Do you have data stored in Parse?

Comment: I've post a link for you in the question, in these link contains screenshot of my parse class and table. waiting to hear from you and thanks for your help!

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot which you can see clearly[here](http://audreyli.me/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/friendlist.jpg)

Comment: In my screenshot there's no from and to column and each user's friend list are kept in relation column which is different from your table. Should I create a new class that looks like you or is there another way to query this? Thanks!

Comment: yeah, I think better to create a new class at Parse like this. Simpler that way.

Comment: I only just created that table in Parse to show you how the demo works. You can recreate it very easily.

Comment: I change how I query my object and it retrieved successfully but it didn't show in tableview, it just print on the log. Do you play facebook or other messaging app? So that I can contact you much faster. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry got caught up in the last two days. Just saw the message. You can wechat me: audreyinbeijing  or email me: me(at)audreyli.me

Comment: I've added you via Wechat. Sorry for taking so long